# Slow list parsing with python3.7 for duplicate item removal

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, bigdata

I'm trying to remove duplicate items from a large text file containing 250 million items at 4.4 Gigabytes.

I was impressed to see that I could load this file into a python list in just a few minutes with the following code:

```
x = []

with open("online.txt") as file:
    for l in file:
       x.append(l)

    print('count of array: ')
    print(len(x))
```

But when I tried to simply check to make sure the next item doesn't exist before added it to an array, it's taking many hours to finish. I feel like I'm missing something simple that would really speed this up.

Here's the code I used to check for duplicate items:

```
a = []
x = []

with open("online.txt") as file:
    for l in file:
        if l in a:
            print('duplicate')
            print(l)
        else:
            x.append(l.strip())
        a.append(l)

    print('with duplicates: ');
    print(len(a))
    print('without duplicates: ')
    print(len(x))
```

This is running on a server with 64 Gigs of ram and modern dual xeon processors.

Comment: that's going to be very slow using lists!  maybe try making `a` a `set()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with a simple list, python has to search through every entry each time before adding a new one.

You could try a python dictionary or a set instead of a list.  These data structures are faster for determining if an entry exists already.

Simply change your code:

```
a = {}  # set
x = {}

with open("online.txt") as file:
    for l in file:
        if l in a:
            print('duplicate')
            print(l)
        else:
            x.add(l.strip())  # add to the set
        a.add(l)
```

You don't specify your input file-format, but there may be speed increases possibly by loading the whole data-set into a giant string, then splitting it up with python functions, rather than manually like you do here.

Comment: The input file is plain text, with one item per line separated by a return. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: How about `words = open("online.txt", "rt").read().replace("\r","").split("\n")` - this will at least read the file in one big chunk, and give you a list of words.  It's hard to say if it will be faster than what you have already.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, here's the code I used to remove duplicates:

```
x = set([])

with open("all.txt") as file:
    for l in file:
       x.add(l)

    print('count of array: ')
    print(len(x))
```

Comment: Note that the explicit loop is unnecessary and slower than just letting Python do the work. `set` takes an arbitrary iterable as an argument and can consume it, deduping as it goes. Just remove the original definition of `x` and the loop, replacing both with just do `x = set(file)` and you get the same result, but *much* faster.

Comment: If you need to preserve order, as of 3.6 in CPython, 3.7 as a language guarantee, `dict`s preserve insertion order (first insertion; duplicates get ignored), and `dict.fromkeys` works very similarly to the `set` constructor otherwise. So `x = dict.fromkeys(file)` would get you a `dict` with the unique keys in the same order they were first seen (on earlier versions of Python, you'd have to use `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, using your version took 133.60 seconds, vs 173.72 seconds with the explicit loop. Also simplified the code nicely.